# Output to CSV generating errors

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I don't have a lot of experience with using the `fputcsv` function.
I'm trying to make a function, by which an admin can download a file with all the user information.

The CSV should be generated in this way :

```
Serial Number   Username     Email    etc etc
```

And then the records from a query.

I have this function which I'm using to generate the csv file :

```
function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    // open raw memory as file so no temp files needed, you might run out of memory though
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
    // loop over the input array
    foreach ($array as $line) { 
        // generate csv lines from the inner arrays
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter); 
    }
    // rewrind the "file" with the csv lines
    fseek($f, 0);
    // tell the browser it's going to be a csv file
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    // tell the browser we want to save it instead of displaying it
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'";');
    // make php send the generated csv lines to the browser
    fpassthru($f);
}
```

And then I call the function:

```
<?php
include 'inc/inc.functions.php';
include 'dbconnector.php';
$query="SELECT * from users order by email LIMIT 0,30";
$result=mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$array=mysql_fetch_array($result);

foreach($array as $arr)
{
array_to_csv_download($arr,"records.csv",":");
}

?>
```

The CSV generated displays: `Warning, Invalid argument supplied for foreach.`

What should I do to display in the way I require?

**UPDATE**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzAbb.png

Comment: `fetch_array()` returns a **SINGLE** row of results. You foreach that, producing individual field values. YOu pass those values into your array_to_csv string, and try to foreach them AGAIN. But they're not arrays, so you get your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently calling your function for a single row in the database, rather than for the entire result set. The following should use your function correctly:

```
$query = "SELECT * from users order by email LIMIT 0,30";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$array = array();

# Headers
$array[] = array("Serial Number","Username","Email","etc etc");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
array_to_csv_download($array,"records.csv",":");
```

Comment: This partially solved the problem mate.
But how am I going to display the headers of the column ?

Comment: I've modified my answer to include a header row

Comment: Hey mate, I'm not sure why everything is repeated twice column wise.
Could you please check it ?
I've uploaded an image.

Comment: I fixed this error by this line :-$array[] = array($row['userid'],$row['firstname'],$row['lastname'],$row['email'],$row['registrationdate']);

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() fetches the column as associate keys as well as numerically indexed ones (so it has each column twice), use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead